# How to change post format from Aside to Image for all posts?

Tags: mysql, post-formats

I have a blog where all the posts had the post format ***Image***.  This morning I see that somehow they have all been changed to ***Aside***.  I'm still trying to figure out how this happened, but in the meantime, how do I go about changing them all back to Image?  Is this something I can do with a SQL statement or do I need to write a custom script to loop through all the posts and save them with the Image post format?  And if a SQL statement would work, any thoughts on what that might look like?

Thanks much,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this right in interface:

1. Select posts in need of change in admin post list screen
2. Select `Edit` in `Bulk actions` dropdown and press `Apply` next to it
3. Choose `Format` > `Image` in interface panel that appeared
4. Press `Update` to apply

Comment: If there aren't enough posts displayed on one page you can also open the "Screen Options" section at the top of the page and display more posts per page.